# Prevent Opera browser from enriching HTML5 fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opera

I'm using loads of inputs with HTML5 types (such as 'date' or 'time') using the jQuery Tools library. Some browsers (like Opera) automatically recognize that and, for example, transform the `<input type="time" />` into a time input.

However, I do not want that behavior (since Opera's time input does not include seconds). Is there any common HTML5 way of disabling such special behavior?

Thanks,
Remo

Comment: That's the purpose of the html5 types to have special UI - the simplest way is to use other types - like just `type=text`.

Comment: As Jakub said, those types ARE the "HTML5 way" of doing things. Use CSS classes and then do whatever you want to to the elements with jQuery.

Comment: Calling 'HTML classes' 'CSS classes' makes even less sense when you're only dealing with them in the context of JavaScript. *sigh*.

Comment: i really don't have a problem with opera here, since their implementation is good, i hate the way chrome handles html5 form fields, especially date, its terrible

Comment: Chrome also doesn't show deconds. Seems like `type='time'` might not be the right feature for you (at least not until it's more customisable). Just use `type='text'`.

Comment: You all are right, type='time' is not the right feature for me because it's giving to much control to the browser itself. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As most of the commenters on the original question already stated:  **No, there is no "common HTML5 way" to prevent this behavior.**

Even if so, you shouldn't. You're effectivly asking Opera to ignore something you asked for in the first place: a special UI.

Comment: ...and even worse: you prevent users from taking advantage of a general UI for custom input types.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a time element on Opera to display seconds, add the attribute `step="1"`, you can get milliseconds by setting `step="0.1"` and `step=60` will give you the default `hh:mm` again.  This also works in Chrome (tested in 9.0.597.98 beta).

Comment: Looks like you saved his day. :)

Comment: Thanks, this actually did me a big favor;)

Comment: If someone wants to read the (working draft) of the HTML5 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#time-state It says: "The default step is 60 seconds."

Comment: @Remo, by the way, take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers

Comment: @DenilsonSá To be fair I think @Kriem answered his question correctly, this is more of an alternative approach